# Syntax error: missing 'closing parenthesis' with indexed fields

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, foreign-key-relationship

I am using MySQL Workbench.
In the line:

```
REFERENCES `mydb`.`Registre` (`idDoc` , `dateDoc` , `idFRP` , `idAudience`)
```

I am getting the error

```
"Syntax error: missing 'closing parenthesis'". 
My field in table Registre indexed 


INDEX `INDEX` (`idMV` ASC, `idAudience` ASC, `idDoc` ASC, `idFRP` ASC, `INN` ASC, `dateDoc` ASC))
```

If any can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the SQL:`

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 04/17/15 10:31:31
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`MaterialValueList`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`MaterialValueList` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`MaterialValueList` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `materialValue` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Audience`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Audience` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Audience` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `auditorium` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`FRP`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`FRP` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`FRP` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `contactInfo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Registre`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Registre` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Registre` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `idMV` INT NOT NULL,
  `idAudience` INT NOT NULL,
  `idDoc` INT NOT NULL,
  `idFRP` INT NOT NULL,
  `INN` INT NOT NULL,
  `count` INT NOT NULL,
  `dateDoc` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `INDEX` (`idMV` ASC, `idAudience` ASC, `idDoc` ASC, `idFRP` ASC, `INN` ASC, `dateDoc` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PurchaseInvoice`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`PurchaseInvoice` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PurchaseInvoice` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `dateDoc` DATE NOT NULL,
  `idFRP` INT NULL,
  `idAudience` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `InvoiceFRPFK_idx` (`idFRP` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_PurchaseInvoice_Audience1_idx` (`idAudience` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_PurchaseInvoice_Registre1_idx` (`id` ASC, `dateDoc` ASC, `idFRP` ASC, `idAudience` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `InvoiceFRPFK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idFRP`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`FRP` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PurchaseInvoice_Audience1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idAudience`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Audience` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PurchaseInvoice_Registre1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` , `dateDoc` , `idFRP` , `idAudience`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Registre` (`idDoc` , `dateDoc` , `idFRP` , `idAudience`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PurchaseInvoiceList`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`PurchaseInvoiceList` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PurchaseInvoiceList` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `idMV` INT NOT NULL,
  `inventoryNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `count` INT NULL,
  `PurchaseInvoiceID` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `InvoiceMaterialFK_idx` (`idMV` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_PurchaseInvoiceList_Registre1_idx` (`idMV` ASC, `inventoryNumber` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_PurchaseInvoiceList_PurchaseInvoice1_idx` (`PurchaseInvoiceID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `InvoiceListMaterialFK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMV`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`MaterialValueList` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PurchaseInvoiceList_Registre1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMV` , `inventoryNumber`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Registre` (`idMV` , `INN`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PurchaseInvoiceList_PurchaseInvoice1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PurchaseInvoiceID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`PurchaseInvoice` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`WriteOff`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`WriteOff` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`WriteOff` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `dateDoc` DATE NOT NULL,
  `idAudience` INT NULL,
  `idFRP` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `WriteOffAudience_idx` (`idAudience` ASC),
  INDEX `WriteOffFRPFK_idx` (`idFRP` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_WriteOff_Registre1_idx` (`id` ASC, `dateDoc` ASC, `idFRP` ASC, `idAudience` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `WriteOffAudienceFK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idAudience`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Audience` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `WriteOffFRPFK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idFRP`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`FRP` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_WriteOff_Registre1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` , `dateDoc` , `idFRP` , `idAudience`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Registre` (`idDoc` , `dateDoc` , `idFRP` , `idAudience`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`WriteOffList`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`WriteOffList` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`WriteOffList` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `idMV` INT NOT NULL,
  `inventoryNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `count` INT NULL,
  `WriteOffID` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `WriteOffListMaterialFK_idx` (`idMV` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_WriteOffList_Registre1_idx` (`idMV` ASC, `inventoryNumber` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_WriteOffList_WriteOff1_idx` (`WriteOffID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `WriteOffListMaterialFK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMV`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`MaterialValueList` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_WriteOffList_Registre1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMV` , `inventoryNumber`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Registre` (`idMV` , `INN`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_WriteOffList_WriteOff1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`WriteOffID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`WriteOff` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`MovingMV`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`MovingMV` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`MovingMV` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `dateDoc` DATE NOT NULL,
  `idFRPto` INT NOT NULL,
  `idAudienceto` INT NOT NULL,
  `idFRPfrom` INT NULL,
  `idAudiencefrom` INT NULL,
  INDEX `MovingMVFEPFK_idx` (`idFRPto` ASC, `idFRPfrom` ASC),
  INDEX `MovingMVAudienceFK_idx` (`idAudienceto` ASC, `idAudiencefrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_MovingMV_Registre1_idx` (`id` ASC, `dateDoc` ASC, `idFRPto` ASC, `idAudienceto` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `MovingMVFEPFK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idFRPto` , `idFRPfrom`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`FRP` (`id` , `id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `MovingMVAudienceFK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idAudienceto` , `idAudiencefrom`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Audience` (`id` , `id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_MovingMV_Registre1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` , `dateDoc` , `idFRPto` , `idAudienceto`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Registre` (`idDoc` , `dateDoc` , `idFRP` , `idAudience`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`MovingMVList`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`MovingMVList` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`MovingMVList` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `idMV` INT NOT NULL,
  `inventoryNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `count` INT NULL,
  `MovingID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_MovingMVList_MaterialValueList1_idx` (`idMV` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_MovingMVList_Registre1_idx` (`idMV` ASC, `inventoryNumber` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_MovingMVList_MovingMV1_idx` (`MovingID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_MovingMVList_MaterialValueList1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMV`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`MaterialValueList` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_MovingMVList_Registre1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMV` , `inventoryNumber`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Registre` (`idMV` , `INN`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_MovingMVList_MovingMV1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`MovingID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`MovingMV` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use the keyword index twice. please remove one: `INDEX`INDEX`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Registre` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `idMV` INT NOT NULL,
  `idAudience` INT NOT NULL,
  `idDoc` INT NOT NULL,
  `idFRP` INT NOT NULL,
  `INN` INT NOT NULL,
  `count` INT NOT NULL,
  `dateDoc` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX  (`idMV` ASC, `idAudience` ASC, `idDoc` ASC, `idFRP` ASC, `INN` ASC, `dateDoc` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```